# How to convert string to components in blazor?

Tags: c#, html, string, dynamic, blazor

I am trying to make a template constructor in which elements are dynamically created.

The difficulty arises when me need to place elements in a panel and simply on a form.

my model:

```
public enum TField
    {
        Edit,
        DatePicker,
        ComboBox,
        DataComboBox,
        Memo,
    }

    public class Field
    {
        public string FieldLabel { get; set; }
        public byte Position { get; set; }
        public TField TypeField { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Panel
    {
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public byte Position { get; set; }
        public List<Field> Field { get; set; }
    }
```

I write all Field in the general List  so that later I will display all the elements

```
 @if (item.TypeComponent != TComponent.Panel)
                    {
                        fieldPanel.Add(DeserializeField(item.Component));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (DeserializePanel(item.Component).Field != null)
                            foreach (var panel in DeserializePanel(item.Component).Field)
                            {
                                fieldPanel.Add(panel);
                            }
                    }
```

to display the elements in the panel me need another loop with the tag BSCard.

```
 @foreach (var field in fieldPanel)
                {
                    <div class="form-group">

                        @if (field.TypeField == TField.Edit)
                        {
                           <label>@field.FieldLabel</label>
                           <InputText Id="CouponCode" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="field.Value"></InputText>
                        }
}
```

I can’t understand how to show components on the form and on the panel without duplication of cycles?

Comment: Have you looked at using RenderFragment? https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/passing-data-to-a-renderfragement/ and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I assume you don't want `Id="CouponCode"` on every field?

Comment: Thank! https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/passing-data-to-a-renderfragement/ is what me need.